# 10,000 foot overview question on SQL Server query composition

Tags: sql-server, layout

I've just migrated from Access where I would "write" SQL constantly and quickly using their GUI layout.  I'm very new to SQL Server and am puzzled why is there no query GUI in SQL Server.  Is it just that much more powerful that a GUI wouldn't be able to address the majority of queries?  Or is it like a purist thing where once one is no longer in watered down databases like Access that he or she should just know SQL well enough to write it on the fly.  Or am wrong altogether, and there IS a graphical way that most programmers compose SQL?

Sorry for the umbrella question, but I think some theory here would help me understand the big picture better.

Comment: What kind of version of sql server are you using?

Comment: Well, I can’t speak for all SQL developers of course, but I’ve learnt SQL the “purist” way (though probably not out of purist motivations, but rather because there wasn’t anything GUI-like available in the old days), and now that I’m familiar with it, I would find a graphical query designer unwieldy, distracting and clunky...

Comment: @Timwi IMHO, I think that this is faster way for developers. The situation is that a lot of managers/auditors/consultants switch form excel or access to some SQL database and than they need such designer to create a data report. For them is faster to create overall view and then tune it in plain SQL that memorizing all structure of database, developer does not need to create such report s sometimes they need to create a view but often this view is so complicated that creation in a designer is much harder. I can't imagine how to tune a query using a designer.

Comment: @Vash apparently there are also a query design tools built in to Microsoft Reporting Services: [Query Design Tools in Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345246.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Server is a database server. That it self does not have any editor text or GUI. You can mange it from the console, or any dedicated software that might have or not a query designer.

The main difference between Access and SQL Server or any other database, is that the MS Access is application that store the data in a file, when You close "Access" anything can happen inside the database by it self, while you are using SQL Server it is alway on You only connect to it. That why access have build nice query, report form designers. The SQL Server has totally different job to do and does not need this. With SQL Server we have Sql Server Management Studio, whit serve to global management not only for table creation and query design, there is a lot of background staff going on right there for example user management, rights jobs.

So it is not that SQL Server does not have a query designer, You just don't use proper software to work with it. A power full application is SSMS that ChrisW presented.

Comment: Sure, but you can access the Access database engine under the covers exactly as you'd access a SQL Server database. And SSMS comes with SQL Server. So I'm not sure there's a practical distinction here?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a `Query Designer` as part of `Sql Server Management Studio`: see for example [SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Query Designer](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1086).

Comment: But I doubt whether "most programmers compose SQL graphically".

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a GUI-Designer for Views and Queries. Just use the  SQL Server Management Studio.

For Example on the "Views" right-click and choose "Add View...". The view GUI is looking very similar to the one in access.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK about MySQL. Earlier there was the MySQL suite of tools and now there is the [MySQL Workbench.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html)

Say what you may, but it's definitely a timesaver.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I believe the query designer in SQL Server Management Studio is probably the equivalent of what you've used in Access. I'm not terribly well-versed in using Access except through code, but I think you can do what you want there (in query designer). I've never found it to be very flexible, so I always end up back in the code itself, but there you go.

My other answer is a little bit off topic (and posted at this point mostly for googlers), but if you're a developer (especially using SQL Server), it probably still applies: Linq to SQL in Visual Studio.

I've been developing against SQL Server databases for about 7 years now, and most of that time has been spent writing the SQL statements out by hand. Last year, I changed jobs and finally had an environment where the databases my programs used were local and didn't change structure. I finally had a good opportunity to begin using Linq!

Linq is an amazingly useful tool!!! I now use it for almost (not quite) all of my database interactions from code.

The basic gist is that you create a graphical database layout in a dbml file. This layout includes tables (or views) as objects and association (PK/FK relationships) as links between the objects. How you set up the associations determines whether that property is a single object or an entity set of that object. Imagine you've got the following:

```
TABLE (ORDERS)       TABLE (CUSTOMERS)
--------------       ----------------
PrimKey
CustomerID --(FK)--> PrimKey
OrderDate            CompanyName
```

Using Linq to SQL, when you run something like the following:

```
Using db as new DataBaseContext
    Dim orders = (From iOrder In db.ORDERS Order By iOrder.Customer.CompanyName).ToList
End Using
```

You end up with a list of Order objects that each own its corresponding Customer object. You can set this up to have object hierarchies and it pretty much works like you'd expect.

Anyway, it's a fairly big topic and more to get into than is appropriate here, but suffice to say that I think it's a great technology to bridge graphical interaction with true, nitty-gritty code.